How can I determine the purpose of wall switches in my home?
In the attached photos you see two 4 way switches at the entrance of a house that are over 100 years old. The left one controls the porch light and it works (but, why a 4 way switch for just a porch light?). The right one does not seem to control anything, but it may be due to the fact that it is old and out of order. These are in the living room that has no light fixtures, but has three receptacles, two of them working, one waiting for my attention.
My testing with different combinations of left right sides of the non-working switch seems to give me some voltage when I pair the upper left button with the ground (i.e. the box) and with the lower right button, when the switch is in the on position. The voltage runs from 85 to about 95.
So how do I find out what these switches are supposed to do? Of course I think I should replace the old stuff but I should want to know what I will be getting. I did replace a three way switch and the combination of those switches (staircase light) does work.
These switches are likely the original from when the house was built, since the wires have cloth insulation and just the look of it.



I may be missing something, but how do you know these are four-way switches?

They look like they could be DPST switches to me.  That is, the lever operates two separate switches at the same time.  For switching two hots together?  Or both hot and neutral.

@keshlam
Somebody edited my original comment. When I said 4 way switches I put a question mark next to it (?). There are 4 screws there so it is at least a 3 way switch. Look at photo 1 and let me know what you think.

@Simon B  But how do I know what it controls and whether it is actually not out of order (the switch seems to be sharp and switching seems to be sturdy, so it is not clear whether it is out of order...)

Four screws does not guarantee that it is a three-way switch either. It could be a switch with a second convenience screw on the hot side to be used to pass voltage to a second switch, just as the second screw on the load side could be a convenience for wiring to loads to the switch. If you don't know the rest of the wiring, the way to determine this is to use a meter to find out what is connected to what in each position of the switch, or to look for labeling on the switch body which says what its function is.

To find out what it controls, see past questions about tracing circuits. If you can't figure it out just by flipping the switch and seeing what happens, you will need a wire tracer which injects a signal into the wire and uses a sensor to follow that signal through your walls. Or, if you have control of everything you need to control, you can declare it a mystery switch and ignore it. There is a switch in my friend's house which has been so ignored for 20 years; it wasn't worth the effort of trying to figure out what it was intended to do.

@keshlam With these switches (over 100 years of age) it will be hard to find any lettering even if it originally was there.

@keshlam Aha, wire tracer sounds interesting. What are they commercially called so I can go out and buy one. It is harder to me to ignore this, than to try to find out what is going on...

@rado: Until they are dismounted, I don't think we know the age of the switches. We know the age of the house, but it may have been completely rewired since then, and certainly switches may have failed and been replaced since then. I may have one toggle switch left in my 1890 house from the original electrification; all the others are clearly much newer.

@keshlam Hmmm. The wires are cloth insulation (I should say rags insulation since it seems to be a cloth of rather ancient period.

@rado: Again, age of the wires does not necessarily tell you age of the switch. Fragile insulation may suggest that you don't want to muck with this unless you absolutely have to, though.
